# Running a bash script as root prevents asynchronous execution?

Tags: bash, shell, permissions, process

The script below get's executed differently if run as a root user.

```
#!/bin/sh

gnome-terminal -x sleep 10 
echo 'Why must I wait for sleep to finish?'
```

If its run as a regular user, message is printed alongside of the newly opened terminal that waits 5 seconds.

If run as a root user, the message isn't printed until the first command doesn't end.

System details:

- Ubuntu 12.4
- `whereis gnome-terminal` is the same for root and standard user

What is the explanation for such behavior?

Comment: I was just investigating this behavior of the script. Interestingly, I found from the root terminal, I can execute the command `gnome-terminal` .

However, if I login as a normal user and try to execute the command `gnome-terminal`, I get the error,

    Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server
    Xlib: No protocol specified

So, it seems like the script is trying to execute something as a non-authorized user and so we are getting different behavior.

Comment: @Ramesh sounds like your X server was started by root, I don't think that is the same behavior as the OP.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What OS are you using?

Comment: the missing `'` at the end of echo is here and not in the script?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this. Both as regular user and with `sudo`, the message is printed as soon as the `gnome-terminal` appears. Apparently, `gnome-terminal` is backgrounded automatically (you can see by running `gnome-terminal` directly from the command line), so the message is printed before the sleep command is finished. It is equivalent to running

```
gnome-terminal -x sleep 10 &
```

If you are really seing a different behavior when run as root, you might have a different `gnome-terminal` in root's $PATH.

Answer (score 1):

When you run script as user, you already have one gnome-terminal window. If you tried to open second gnome-terminal window, it sends info to first and selfcloses (the same situation with Firefox, Chromium).
When you run script as superuser, superuser have not gnome-terminal windows.

Try to close all gnome-terminal windows and run "gksu gnome-terminal". The script will behave same as user.